Using dynamic backend from auth like server in nginx
I am trying to make a system where we route to different backend based on claims in jwt of incoming request.
I have working secondary server that spits out the backend given the request url and jwt in the request but nginx is ignoring my backend value that is set from lua block.
This is the yaml of ingress that I have:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: docs-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      access_by_lua_block {
        local cjson = require("cjson")
        local http = require "resty.http"

        local default_backend="docs1"
        local httpc = http.new()
        local res, err = httpc:request_uri("http://authserver.ingress-nginx-helpers.svc.cluster.local:5000/find-backend", {
          method = "POST",
          body = cjson.encode({ real_url = ngx.var.request_uri }),
          headers = {
            ["Content-Type"] = "application/json",
            ["Token"] = ngx.req.get_headers()['token'],
            ["cookie"] = ngx.req.get_headers()['cookie']
          }
        })

        local response, decode_err = cjson.decode(res.body)
        if not response then
          ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Failed to decode response: ", decode_err)
          ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name = ngx.var.namespace .. "-" .. default_backend .. "-5000"
        else
          ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name = ngx.var.namespace .. "-" .. response.backend .. "-5000"
        end
      }

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: hello.world.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: docs1
            port:
              number: 5000
        path: /api/v1/docs1/docs/custom/
        pathType: Exact

The request is reaching "authserver" with it returning right value but the value defined in .spec.rules.[].http.paths.[].backend.service is used.
Edit: Removed unnecessary information.

Adding ngx.ctx.balancer=nil at the end fixed the issue.
This was due to ingress-nginx internally caching the the specific balancers during the rewrite phase of the request. So setting this to nil here will force nginx to refetch the balancer in its balancer phase based on the newly set proxy_upstream_name from above lua.
This can be streamlined by making a plugin and in each ingress where this requirement is required, setting a variable in the configuration snippet. That variable will be checked in the plugin and decision to execute this lua is taken there.
so final plugin will contain lua like:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ngx-custom-script
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  main.lua: |
    local _M = {}

    local cjson = require("cjson")
    local http = require "resty.http"
    .
    .
    .
    <Rest of the lua code>

and the ingress resource where you want to run this plugin would have a annotation like:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      set $dynamic_plugin "on";

